# Does the worst PCIe MSI interrupt latency jitter over 100us normal?

Tags: linux-kernel, performance, interrupt, irq

I try to figure out the values of interrupt jitter in Linux, especially in the worst cases.
Two testbeds are considered, one is Raspberry Pi 4B, the other is a high-end PC with an intel i9 CPU and ASUS motherboard.

```
   +-+ +-+ +-+     Raspberry Pi 4B
   | | | | | |   -------------+
 --+ +-+ +-+ +-   1. GPIO     |              +--------------+
Signal Generator              |              |              |
                              +----> +-----+ |    Linux     |
                                     | CPU | | ------------ |
                              +----> +-----+ |    Kernel    |
       |  |                   |              |              |
     +-+--+-+     2. PCIe MSI |              +--------------+
   --+ FPGA +--   ------------+
     +-+--+-+      high-end PC (i9-9900K)
       |  |
```

For the Raspberry Pi, a signal generator, which outputs fixed-frequency square waves, is used as the interrupt source. As for the high-end PC, a Xilinx FPGA board with PCIe is used as the interrupt source, and the interrupt type is MSI. Both the signal generator and the Xilinx FPGA board can generate interrupts with little time jitters (<1us).

The following is the `irq_handler` function of the driver code in the Raspberry Pi 4B

```
static irqreturn_t gpio_ts_handler(int irq, void *arg) {

    struct timespec64 timestamp;
    struct gpio_ts_devinfo *devinfo;
    int nwritten;

    ktime_get_real_ts64(&timestamp);   // get the time

    // lock the data fifo and insert the timestamp
    spin_lock(&devinfo->spinlock);
    nwritten = gpio_fifo_write(devinfo->fifo, &timestamp, 1);
    spin_unlock(&devinfo->spinlock);
    if (nwritten != 1) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "GPIOTS: ISR fifo overflow\n");
    }

    // wake up the waiting thread which then read timestamp from the fifo
    wake_up(&devinfo->waitqueue);

    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}
```

The following is the `irq_handler` function of the driver code in the high-end PC

```
// IRQ handler
static irqreturn_t fPCI_event_isr (int irq, void *cookie)
{
    struct timespec64 tsc_now = {.tsc_high = 0; .tsc_low = 0};
    struct fPCI_dev *drv_data =  (struct fPCI_dev *) cookie;
    int nwritten;
    int fifo_size;
   
    // get TSC timestamp
    get_tsc_cpuid((tsc_now.tsc_high), (tsc_now.tsc_low));
    spin_lock(&(drv_data->spin_lock));
    nwritten = fpci_fifo_write(drv_data->fifo, &tsc_now, 1);
    spin_unlock(&(drv_data->spin_lock));
    if (nwritten != 1)
        printk(KERN_INFO, "fPCI_event_isr: fifo overflow!\n");
    
    fifo_size = fpci_fifo_size(drv_data->fifo);
    if (fifo_size > FIFO_SIZE/2)
        wake_up(&(drv_data->waitqueue));
    
    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}
```

In the code of IRQ handlers, first, the current time is stored in a FIFO. Then, a user-space thread reads time data from the FIFO, and counts the jitters of the interrupt.
The results are showed in following two figures.

[image]

[image]

My Question are:

1 Why the PCIe MSI interrupts have larger latency jitters than the GPIO interrupt's ?

2 Is it normal that the morden PCIe MSI interrupt have about 100us latency variation under the worst condition (Is there anything I missed)? How can I minimize such variations in latency (jitter).

Comment: If you want less variation,  you would need to make it higher priority.

Comment: @stark the `irq_handler` is running in the context of the interrupt, as the `top half`, it already has more privileges than normal user/kernel process. Only the `bottom half` priority of the ISR can be set to 99, and it does nothing to do with our top-half interrupt handler.

Comment: Not talking about process priority. https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0337/e/Exceptions/Exception-priority/Priority-levels